# My user registration data isn't passing to the login route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

```js
usersRouter.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const user = new User ({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    })
    try {
        await user.save();
        res.redirect(201, '../users/login') /* 200 means accepted status, 201 created resource */
    } catch {
        res.redirect(500, 'users/register') /* Internal server error */
    }
    });
    
    
  usersRouter.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.find({email: req.body.email})
    console.log(user)
    if (!user)  { 
        return res.send('User does not exist')
    } 
    try {
        if (!await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
            return res.status(401).send('password failed') /* user Unauthorized */
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send('password validated');
            }
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err.message)
    }
})
```

**In /register path**

When I try to make a request, console.log(req.body) = [Object: null prototype] { name: 'p', email: 'p@p', password: '1' }

**In /login path**

console.log(user) = [], instead of the registered user

console.log(user.email) = undefined; instead of the registered user email

Comment: Technically, you can do a 307 redirect and it will force the same request to be made to the new URL. But, why are you redirecting to '/users/login' after registration? You know the login is going to work, since you are passing the same username/password. So, why can't you just log the user in with registration?

Comment: @MarkS. Ok but the login page still doesn't work even though I redirect the user to the homepage in the registration. correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is the body not being sent to the /login path after a 307? Is the data not being shown on the login page?

Comment: @MarkS. if I write res.redirect(307, '../users/login') in the /register route, I can't access /login, received this message: Illegal arguments: string, undefined

Comment: The redirect should be '/users/login' since that's the url you want to go to